# IEnumerable<T>.Concat -- A replacement that can work without changing the reference?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, concatenation

I've recently been bitten by the (way too commmon in my opinion) gotcha of `Concat` returns it's result, rather than appending to the list itself.

For instance.

```
List<Control> mylist=new List<Control>;
//.... after adding Controls into mylist
MyPanel.Controls.Concat(mylist); //This will not affect MyPanel.Controls at all.

MyPanel.Controls=MyPanel.Controls.Concat(mylist); //This is what is needed, but the Controls reference can not be reassigned (for good reason)
```

So is there some other way of combining two lists that will work when the collection reference is read-only?

Is the only way to do this with a foreach?

```
foreach(var item in mylist){
  MyPanel.Controls.Add(item);
}
```

Is there a better way without the foreach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many collections have an AddRange method, [winforms ControlCollection is one of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.addrange.aspx).

```
MyPanel.Controls.AddRange(mylist.ToArray());
```

This has the benefit of telling the container you'll be adding many controls at once, so it may delay layout steps until it's done adding all of them.

Comment: Hmm.. I looked at the arguments and didn't even connect the `ToArray` function with using that...

Comment: OTOH wrt your question about "combining two lists",  List<T>.AddRange  accepts  IEnumerable<T>  so you can pass another List directly in.

Comment: Adding the ToArray call really doesn't accomplish much except ensure that `mylist` is enumerated twice instead of once.

Comment: @Joel: ControlCollection.AddRange takes an array, not List, as argument, the ToArray is not optional in the example shown.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I assumed it was like other AddRanges, which take `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks about IEnumerable, and the answer to that is always "No" - an IEnumerable is a forward-only "stream" of items.

However, if you can use a more Specialized type - ICollection, IList etc. - then you can use the Add or AddRange methods if available.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items) {
    foreach(T item in items) collection.Add(item);
}
```

Then you have:

```
anyGenericCollection.AddRange(someSequence);
```

Of course some collections (`List<T>`, `ControlCollection` etc) already *have* an `AddRange` - this simply makes it available to those that don't.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to extend ICollection, not IList, in order to cover types like LinkedList?

Comment: @Ben - quite possibly ;-p (fixed)

Answer (score 0):

In the off-chance you prefer capitalized ForEach over lowercase foreach:

```
mylist.ForEach(MyPanel.Controls.Add);
```